# Load/Save Binding xaml

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, binding

[image]

[image]

I develop my project for binding 'xml filedata(Absolute Path in Computer) - treeview' on Canvas.
And next step is Save Canvas by XamlWriter. (Treeview in Canvas)

I Succeed save xaml file and Clear My MainWindow.

And Next, Empty MainWindow load saved xaml file to occur Error!

Error is

> "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException"
>   (System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'An exception was thrown when adding a value to a dictionary of type' 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary' '. The line number '1' and the line position '1441')
>
> ArgumentException : ArgumentException: Item already added. Key in dictionary: 'template' Added key: 'template'

I just Want Save and Clear, finally Load Canvas.

But 'Key' has to occur Problem.(I think)
I do not know how to solve this problem.

Please Help ...

Comment: Since you're want to save *XAML*, I almost sure that you're doing something wrong. What is your final goal? Why don't save some serializable model instead of markup?

Comment: @Dennis I Edit My Question. Please Help...

Comment: Is the storage method wrong?

Comment: Why save the XAML? Why not just save the data, then reload and rebind it?

Comment: because FrameWorkElement(TreeView) has Unique properties(Width, Height, Position ...). This Project Goal is make develop tool like mini visual studio.
Edit UI and Give Unique Properties Save that and Anytime Load Saved Work...
So, I should save XAML for Unique Property.
you think same flow Visual Studio or Other Develop Tools.... Plz Help me